# Type based on optional property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a type that types a function based on the `arrayOrNot` property the catch here is I need to have a default type for when `arrayOrNot` is not passed.

Here is a code Snipped that explains.

```
interface TestInner<IsArray> {
    arrayOrNot?: IsArray,
    func: (val: IsArray extends true ? string[] : string)=>void
}
interface TestDefault {
    func: (val: string)=>void
}


type TestType  = TestDefault | TestInner<false> | TestInner<true>

const thing : TestType = {
    // Does not work! val has type any and I need it to be type srting by default
    func: (val)=>{
        console.log({val})
    }
}

const thing2 : TestType = {
    arrayOrNot: false,
    // Works! val is a string[]
    func: (val)=>{
        console.log({val})
    }
}
const thing3 : TestType = {
    arrayOrNot: true,
    // Works! val is a string
    func: (val)=>{
        console.log({val})
    }
}
```

Here is a [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=17&pln=20&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5gJIhNAHmwwEEoo4BPAPmQG8AoZZ5OcqgeSgDkB7MAPwAuZMTIVKAGiYsYAVxAIRACgBucADYix7SsggAPSCAAmGZGChyUA5FiigA5gG0AushH2nASgC81VV5gEwYAXwZQSFhEFHQsABEIeDkNMHoZZnlFFXUtO0sff0DgsIYysEoAB1jMMFQqlGRfNFrE5NTkAB8WrFx8KAJ4DQwIWm64nDxCS2tqMoReECwLAAsnDx66hqb0lmQAen3keN5MZBB+ZAB3XigAawBCZFzkFbhzCurWED04U1FzhAICZkMA0mBeMgAEYoT4oDBQMDrKF6ExJOApMAZZBZJTINSaPzURh7PYLJa8DQQAB0Gl4jmUdFyoW82PC4QY5OWYDWIEcACYNhN6l9miSWGwJFw+GAREMRtI9odkAB1W53DBPF7AcxwfIOPlubG4nKE-zi0nILmUml0hlMzQstmlLng3mOADMQtqIpQYuxks4PH4IhmEEVLGVavumuemlBuv1TmNCjxBI0RItpOtVNp9MZzNZe3ZZSAA) to demo

Answer (score 1):

A simple discriminated unions works best here:

```
type TestType  = {
    arrayOrNot: true,
    func: (val: string[])=>void
} | {
    arrayOrNot?: false,
    func: (val: string)=>void
}

const thing : TestType = {
    func: (val)=>{ // string
        console.log({val})
    }
}

const thing2 : TestType = {
    arrayOrNot: false,
    func: (val)=>{ //string
        console.log({val})
    }
}
const thing3 : TestType = {
    arrayOrNot: true,
    func: (val)=>{ // string[]
        console.log({val})
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmlAvFA3gKCnqAhgE5EEgDyRAcgPbABcUwRArhADS74BmLAdgGNGACgBuBADaNERAJZ8A5gG0AugEo0APlE1ZAE2wBfKAB8sXPMVIVqdAPyNuk+BwtRegkeKlQZ8hRraugaG2NgCNHyITAAW-lCMcIjIkOjm+O78QlBikoGYUAD0hb7M-m4ZEVE0EhAAdBI0CsKY3oZqbqGh4ZHRwHGKAEwJsAhIKGk4GVZklLQM7s6uGR7ZuRL5RYV+ihX4VfA19Y3NrZLtnUY9UcCx-gDMI0njqRhT+DM284zMbJwrWS8eS0BWKpTkilUezwByODSaLTaHQyXTCQA)